# Why is the following question on hold and what should I change?

Tags: support, on-hold, debugging-questions

My question, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562446/how-to-use-curl-from-c-on-windows*, is on hold, because it is seeking debugging help. I have read both *https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions* and *https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic* and still can't figure out what is wrong with it.

I know I wrote it quickly and so the English is not that good, but I think that every person knowing the answer would instantly understand the problem and answer me... What is wrong with that question and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you really believe that posting that huge log dump is necessary?

Comment: When there is a length limit I guess it was wisely chosen so I made use of whole size, but ok, I make it shorter. That was the problem?

Comment: Btw, it's not even log dump, but standart output from ld (linker). It's meant for programmer (human) to find problems.

Comment: Your log dump is so huge you cannot even format it properly anymore.

Comment: It is so far beyond what is considered a reasonable question at SO that explaining why already looks like an insurmountable task.  You'll have to spend some time at SO, looking at the way other programmers ask questions.

Comment: So.... There is a reason why the close vote says you need a MINIMAL example... This output is anything but minimal... In the "how to ask" from the help center it says "ask as if you were asking a busy colleague". The fact you hit the size limit with nothing but four sentences and ONE output should make you question if it's appropriate here. Anyway, considering the output is for a human to read and fix... Did you try? Because from how the question looks now it feels like you threw it on SO, hoping someone else eould read n interpret it, when it is feasible for you to....

Comment: @HansPassant: No, please do not hold up the average question as a model. One can't even recommend taking a look at the most highly-upvoted questions. If you want to give examples, you'll need to supply them manually.

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't think it's necessary, but I wanted to show experienced crossplatform programmers that there is a lot of dependencies and that was the point => I could prolly fix it, but installing all the dependencies would take a lot of time and effort and that's why I ask if there is a better way.

Comment: @Patrice I would pass it as it is to a busy college, because as described, the point is, that it needs a lot of dependencies which can be seen from the output.

Comment: I now understand that It's the output of the linker when you build/compile your code but, it's huge... And as @Patrice wrote in their comment: **"ask as if you were asking a busy colleague"**. I think you should try and make your question on-topic and then the community will vote if to reopen it (I can't give you specific instructions because it's been awhile since the last time I developed in C++, but **actual code** is always a good bet). You can also delete your question because you're in the hostile [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) zone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question has all the signs of being an lazy dump of work for others to sort out. You claim there are *a lot of dependencies* but [I doubt that](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/libs.html).

You didn't state (you were obviously in hurry) if you used a binary pre-build version of libcurl or if you build it yourself from the [git repo where you disabled features](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html). On that same page I read

> When building an application that uses the static libcurl library on Windows, you must add -DCURL_STATICLIB to your CFLAGS. Otherwise the linker will look for dynamic import symbols.

From what I recall from my little experience that could be related. Had you done some research, just like I just did, you could have included which options you used to build your program. And I wouldn't have stopped after trying one option.

But you didn't do all that. Instead you tried to copy-paste the linker errors verbatim into your question and left it at that.

There will not be a single future visitor that will find your question easy to understand or even determine if their problem is similar to yours because all we have is a bunch of errors. There is no reproducible context described and that makes your question close worthy at first sight, highly unlikely to be salvageable and is best deleted. And as there is no value for future visitors let's not spend our time on trying to answer such questions. I have better things to do.

Comment: Ok, now I see how it looks like for people that haven't experienced the same situation. Thanks for effort, but I still don't get why people care about questions they know nothing about :( I thought that adding build options wouldn't add any information. I tried -DCURL_STATICLIB to G++ so specifying that also doesn't add any information. But ok, I should add that I installed the libcurl instead of building it on my own. And for me, adding all of the dependencies from your first link on Windows is not easy and maybe not even possible, because they are standalone and IMHO intended for Linux.